# How to generate access token on OS version 19 for payment gateway

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, android-studio

This code is working in os version 5.1 and above.

Access token is not generated in 5.0 os version and below.

// getting exception ssl layer connection closed by peer

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "grant_type=client_credentials");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://uatapi.nationstrust.com:8243/token")
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .addHeader("authorization", "Basic N000SDNmU3RtVERuZmZ1R0JNMlBGR1FXdmtFYTpEQUFJcEprVUhjdXBwcEx4dkRPSkFYZjNwMmth")
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String test = response.body().string();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println(test);
            } else {
                System.out.println(response.code() +" : "+ response.message());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

//// here I have posted full code what I am trying to generate access token.

[image]